# How to properly access an Android java class using Pyjnius

Tags: java, python, pyjnius

I am having a hard time trying to use Pyjnius to access a Android Java class "ContactsContract.Intents.Insert".

I have  been following this example provided here:

Pyjnius: http://kivy.org/planet/2012/08/pyjnius-accessing-java-classes-from-python/

Java class to access: MediaRecorder

But really what I want to access using Pyjnius is the "ContactsContract.Intents.Insert" in Android and get working code to add a new contact to my Android phone.

Android class: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.html

This is what I have so far but I am confused on the arraylist:

```
from jnius import autoclass

Data = autoclass("ArrayList")
data = Data()

MyContacts = autoclass("ContactsContract.Intents.Insert")

mycontacts = MyContacts()
data.put(Data.MIMETYPE, Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
data.put(Organization.COMPANY, "Android")
data.add(mycontacts)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intents.Insert is a static class which contains static string constants. I had the same problem when I wanted to add contacts from the app I was building. I ended up writing a class containing a static method which would add a contact in java and adding it into my buildozer.spec file for compilation. I know its not exactly what you are after but it gives you a fair idea when running into these kinds of issues there is a work around. It's actually fairly easy to mix Python code with Java. Kivy is great for prototyping Android apps but like pyjnius the documentation is very limited.

Java code

```
import android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.Intents;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;

public class Contact{

    public static void addContact(Activity pyActivity, String name, String phone, String email){
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
        i.setType(Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
        i.putExtra(Intents.Insert.NAME, name);
        i.putExtra(Intents.Insert.PHONE, phone);
        i.putExtra(Intents.Insert.EMAIL, email);
        pyActivity.startActivity(i);
    }

}
```

python script

```
PythonActivity = autoclass("org.kivy.android.PythonActivity")
Contact = autoclass("Contact")
Contact.addContact(PythonActivity.mActivity, "Steve", "666", "steve666@gmail.com")
```

and then finally add the Conact.java to the buildozer.spec file

```
android.add_src = Contact.java
```

Comment: Where did you put the java code exactly? I'm trying to do something similar.

Comment: Near main.py file. And it works fine. Btw THANKS for this helpful answer.